# Are there any libraries available that enable IE9 style pinning in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

Are there any libraries available that enable IE9 style pinning, as seen here:
http://buildmypinnedsite.com/en

I'm not looking to pin tabs like in Firefox, but rather to implement the custom icon in the Windows 7 taskbar with custom thumbnails and notifications (see link above and it will all make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a IE9/Win7 only feature. It doesn't work with other browser, at least not without a plug-in. Firefox used to have an add-on named [Prism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-labs-prism/) but it doesn't update any more.